# Getting an account's media from the Instagram Business Discovery API.

Tags: instagram

I want to get recent media from a selection of third-party Business Accounts on Instagram.

The [Business Discovery API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/business-discovery) appears to be built for just this purpose

However, the response contains Media IDs rather than URLs to the media itself.

[image]

I can't find an endpoint where I can GET(Media) by ID.

Any advice?

Comment: You may be able to access the media directly from the Instagram API, although when I tried with the ids listed above, I get "invalid media id' response.  Try using that in combination with "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/?access_token=youraccesstoken"

Comment: any luck? I am looking into this currently and there isn't much documentation out there. Feels like trial and error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the media details using the following query.

Ex:

> ?fields=business_discovery.username(USERNAME){id,followers_count,media_count,ig_id,media{caption,media_url,media_type,like_count,comments_count,timestamp,id}}